# Using Logback in bridged java method for React Native

Tags: java, android, react-native, logging, logback

I'm trying to modify working app. I installed logback for android from this repository -> https://github.com/tony19/logback-android And after that I created bridged method for in java file, which was originally bridged and contains other @reactmethod methods.

Here is my java code (not full code, just logback things):

```
package com.eeg_project.components.classifier;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class ClassifierModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements BufferListener {

    // Logback
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassifierModule.class);

    @ReactMethod
    public void startSaveCSV() {

        //test ints
        int a = 2;
        int b = 2;

        String csvLine = a + "," + b;
        logger.info(csvLine);
    }
}
```

My logback.xml is configured like this:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] %logger - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FILE-APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>/storage/emulated/0/Download/Data.csv</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="com.eeg_project.components.classifier.ClassifierModule" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-APPENDER" />
    </logger>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

And here is the code for recat native to call bridged method from java (sandboxbutton is original app button, I just changed it's function):

```
import Classifier from "../native/Classifier";

  }

   <SandboxButton onPress={() => Classifier.startSaveCSV()}>CSV</SandboxButton>
```

App compiles cuccesfully, but the problem occurs when I tap my button. Nothing happens :( App doesn't even create my Data.csv file..

Any sloution?.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration of `logback.xml` was wrong. Here is my solution:

```xml
<configuration>
    <!-- Create a file appender for a log in the application's data directory -->
    <appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>/data/data/com.eeg_project/files/log/eegdata.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- Write INFO (and higher-level) messages to the log file -->
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```